# Loop through directory and remove csv headers with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, header, directory

I'm trying to loop through the directory DirIn, remove the first two lines from each csv file, and then save those files in a new directory DirOut. The following code is what I've pieced together from other forums, but I cannot get the code to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
gci "DirIn\*.csv" | % {(gc $_ | select -Skip 2) | sc "DirOut\$_" }
```

Comment: When making powershell csv files. I always add -notypeinformation to prevent these issues. This doesn't solve your problem. But may prevent it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gci "DirIn\*.csv" | % {(gc $_ | select -Skip 2) | sc "DirOut\$($_.Name)" }
```

Comment: The only difference to OPs line is `.Name` property of the no more valid `$_` variable it now contains the lines from gc. BTW the alias `sc` is/will be removed from PSv6 core versions. You could use `ForEach ($File in (gci "DirIn\*.csv")){(gc $File | select -Skip 2) | Set-Content "DirOut\$($File.Name)" }`

Comment: @LotPings: No: Since the `$_` in the `sc` command is referenced as part of an _argument_, it still refers to the `gci`-produced output object, so this is a viable solution, and generally preferable to using a `foreach` loop.
Good point about `sc` in PowerShell _Core_.

Comment: To explain why this answer works: `$_` by itself would expand to each input file's _full path_, whereas only the _filename part_ is desired, which `$($_.Name)` provides.
The surrounding `$(...)` is needed to embed an _expression_ such as `$_.Name` in a double-quoted string, because only simple variable references such as `$var` can be embedded directly - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You're losing your `$_` reference to the file when piping inside the `ForEach-Object` loop. Use the `-PipelineVariable` parameter to get around that.

```
gci "DirIn\*.csv" -PipelineVariable 'File' | % {(gc $File | select -Skip 2) | sc "DirOut\$($File.Name)" }
```

Comment: There is no need for `-PipelineVariable` in this case, because the `$_` is being referred to in the `sc` command inside an _argument_ in the OP's case, in which case `$_` still has the `gci`-produced value, so changing `$_` to `$($_.Name)` is enough. In short: @Nas' answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

To show LotPings answer in a readable and maintainable format...

```
ForEach ($File in (Get-ChildItem "DirIn\*.csv")) {
    (Get-Content $File | Select-Object -Skip 2) |
        Set-Content "DirOut\$($File.Name)"
}
```

Best practice is to not use aliases in script files.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'd like to understand what's happening a bit better. Why is it DirOut\$($File.Name) instead of DirOut\$File.Name?

Comment: If `DirOut\$File.Name` is not expanded, then `$File` will be interpreted alone, followed by the string ".Name". This would produce a name such as `DirOut\sample.csv.Name`.

Comment: Sorry, the name without expansion might be something like `DirOut\C:\DirIn\sample.csv.Name`.

Comment: All you're doing with this solution is to forgo the pipeline's object-by-object processing by collecting all `Get-ChildItem` output in memory up front, which isn't necessary. There is no need to switch to `foreach`, and @Nas' answer is the better choice (@LotPing's criticism didn't apply).